# How to disable autofocus in WooCommerce forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have added [woocommerce_order_tracking] shortcode into my website home page and since then every time I refresh or first visit in it, the whole page scrolls down to the first input of the form generated with [woocommerce_order_tracking].

I have researched online about and found it caused by the "autofocus" attribute. WordPress add it automatically, and I don't know how to disable it or make the page load on top. 
I tried to plant some JS and Jquery codes inside the head tag and even at the body.. with no much success.

can anyone help me solve this issue? I like the form and how it look like, I only don't want that the page will scroll to it automatically...

website address: http://blackbmb.com/store

`<input class="input-text" type="text" name="orderid" id="orderid" placeholder="Found in your order confirmation email." required="" autofocus="">`

Thank you!
Yahav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add this to my functions.php, to stop the same thing happening to the firstname field. Just amend with whatever fields apply to you:

```
//Disable autofocus and thus autoscroll    
function disable_autofocus_firstname($fields) {
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['autofocus'] = false;
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','disable_autofocus_firstname');
```

Let me know if it works :)